# MarkLogic-typescript-definition library Update for ML 9.0.5

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

My application is using old MarkLogic-typescript-definitions library for javascript and from ML 9.0.5 ValueIterator has been changed to Sequence. I need to update my application to use the latest MarkLogic-typescript-definition library for ML 9.0.5.

Please suggest a way to update the library.

Comment: I'll have a look at refreshing https://github.com/grtjn/marklogic-typescript-definitions..

Comment: thank you so much currently, I am using the same repository for typescript definition

Comment: It would make more sense to have filed this as an issue on GitHub, or to comment on/upvote an issue if there already had been one.

Comment: I created a ticket for this, since a lot seems to have changed since ML8: https://github.com/grtjn/marklogic-typescript-definitions/issues/20

Comment: @AshutoshTrivedi could you run a test with the 0.5.0 tag of what is currently on github? Haven't published to npm yet, some confirmation before hand would be nice..

Comment: Yes i will do and let you know

Comment: while integration this tagged version I am getting the following error - node_modules/marklogic-typescript-definitions/ts/types.d.ts(1,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
we are using type-script 2.5.2. Is this related to type-script version or something else.

Comment: Please help @grtjn for my above query

Comment: Yes, you need typescript 2.9.2+, as mentioned here: https://github.com/grtjn/marklogic-typescript-definitions#suggested-typescript-editors

Comment: it is giving same error with typescript 2.9.2

Comment: Remove the reference, and run `npm i --save-dev @types/node`. After that VS Code shows clean for me..

Comment: latest marklogic typescript definition  gives a compilation error Duplicate identifier 'require'  ie the function declare function require(location: string): Object; gives compilation error please help

Comment: node/index.d.ts has the same function as define in marklogic typescript definition I am using node 10.5.2 version

Comment: I also face one more compilation error for interface IteratorResult<T> {
  done: boolean
  value?: T
} as the same is defined in lib.es6.d.ts. Please help

Comment: @grtjn please help for the above three queries

Comment: This is getting too chatty for comments. Could you please create a github ticket?

Answer (score 2):

The steps to compile the typescript definitions with latest MarkLogic apidocs are described in full detail in the project README:

https://github.com/grtjn/marklogic-typescript-definitions#building-the-typescript-definitions

HTH!